# Maximum capacity of STL queue

Tags: c++, queue

What is the maximum capacity of an STL queue, considering that it holds ints.  By maximum capacity I mean the max number of integers it can hold at maximum capacity.

thanks

Comment: Are you using an embedded processor or an IBM mainframe with 1500GB of RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C++ Reference holds an answer for that.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/max_size/)
In the end, it relies on the underlying container of `std::queue`. Its `max_size` is also the `max_size` of the queue.

Answer (score 4):

There's a big difference between theoretical maximum as returned by queue::max_size() and actual maximum.  You probably only ever really care about the latter, but there's no way to find out until it is too late.  It heavily depends on the state of the heap and the virtual memory address space.